# SQL Server 2008: How to find trailing spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I find all column values in a column which have trailing spaces? For leading spaces it would simply be

```
select col from table where substring(col,1,1) = ' ';
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can find trailing spaces with `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '% '
```

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but i would like to know, if i would like to check if any columns in my table contain trailing spaces? Btw i got 45 fields in the table...how can i do so?

Comment: @10e5x That is a different question. I recommend you post it as a different question. :-)

Comment: @rodrigocprates: It depends. One option could be to create an additional BIT column to store a calculated value (trigger time?) of whether or not the field ends with a space. Another option would be to create a Computed Column to do the same thing. Or perhaps an indexed View to do the same thing. Lastly, something to try (it might be worse, or not) would be to use substrings to grab the last character and see if it is a space, although I suspect it would be slower.

Comment: To remove it: `UPDATE tablename SET columnname = RTRIM(columnname)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14782025/1494454).

Answer (score 9):

SQL Server 2005:

```
select col from tbl where right(col, 1) = ' '
```

As a demo:

```
select 
    case when right('said Fred', 1) = ' ' then 1 else 0 end as NoTrail,
    case when right('said Fred ', 1) = ' ' then 1 else 0 end as WithTrail
```

returns

```
NoTrail WithTrail
0       1
```

Answer (score 6):

A very simple method is to use the LEN function.
LEN will trim trailing spaces but not preceeding spaces, so if your LEN() is different from your LEN(REVERSE()) you'll get all rows with trailing spaces:

```
select col from table where LEN(col) <> LEN(REVERSE(col));
```

this can also be used to figure out how many spaces you have for more advanced logic.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

```
select * from table_name where column_name not like RTRIM(column_name)
```

This will give you all the records that have trailing spaces.

If you want to get the records that have either leading or trailing spaces then you could use this:

```
select * from table_name where column_name not like LTRIM(RTRIM(column_name))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE LEN(col) != DATALENGTH(col)
```

Should work also.

Comment: Only where col is not nvarchar.

Comment: Good catch. According to http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic431183-8-1.aspx for `nvarchar` we should compare just to half of `DATALENGTH` value.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different ways to do this...

My favorite option, assuming your intention is to remove any leading and / or trailing spaces, is to execute the following, which will dynamically create the T-SQL to `UPDATE` all columns with an unwanted space to their trimmed value:

```
SELECT 
'UPDATE [<DatabaseName>].[dbo].['+TABLE_NAME+']
SET ['+COLUMN_NAME+']=LTRIM(RTRIM(['+COLUMN_NAME+']))
WHERE ['+COLUMN_NAME+']=LTRIM(RTRIM(['+COLUMN_NAME+']));'+CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '<TableName>%' 
    AND DATA_TYPE!='date'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
```

If you really need to identify them though, try one of these queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM [database].[schema].[table]
WHERE [col1]!=LTRIM(RTRIM([col1]))
```

More dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''['+TABLE_NAME+'].['+COLUMN_NAME+']'',*
FROM [<your database name>].[dbo].['+TABLE_NAME+']
WHERE ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] LIKE ''% ''
    OR ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] LIKE '' %'';
GO
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '<filter table name as desired>%'
    AND DATA_TYPE!='date'
```

Comment: In what way is it over the top?

Comment: SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '% '

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to find records with leading or trailing whitespace, including tabs etc:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE NOT TRIM(col) = col
```

Comment: There is no `TRIM` function in SQL Server and trailing spaces are ignored in `=` comparisons anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I thought that was standard SQL. It works in PostgreSQL as expected though, and I found this question because i was trying to solve the same problem with PostgreSQL, so perhaps it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are ignored in SQL Server so for me even the leading space was not working .

```sql
select col from table where substring(col,1,1) = ' '
```

wont work if there is only one space (' ') or blank ('')

so I devised following:

```sql
select * from [table] where substring(REPLACE(col, ' ', '#'),1,1) = '#'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "spaces are ignored in SQL Server..."? Perhaps you mean in the context of the substring function?

Comment: @SQL_Underworld Not sure what OP meant, but for an actual db value of 'test ', I had the row returned for all of 1. `where test like 'test'`, 2. `'where test like 'test '`, 3. `where test = 'test'` and 4. `where test='test '`. I also found that `len(test)` was 4 instead of 5. So it seems like all of len, like and = simply ignored the trailing space. The substring trick that Thunder suggests did replace the space with a #, so that len, like and = could be used. This is possibly encoding-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative for trailing spaces.

```
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50) = NULL

DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50) = '  '

IF ((@VALUE IS NOT NULL) AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(@VALUE)) != ''))

BEGIN
   SELECT 'TRUE'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT 'FALSE'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Battles
SET name = CASE WHEN (LEN(name+'a')-1)>LEN(RTRIM(name))
THEN REPLICATE(' ', (LEN(name+'a')-1)- LEN(RTRIM(name)))+RTRIM(name)
ELSE name
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the accepted answer a little bit slower:

```
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '% ';
```

against this technique:

```
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE ASCII(RIGHT([value], 1)) = 32;
```

The idea is to get the last char, but compare its `ASCII` code with the `ASCII` code of space instead only with `' '` (space). If we use only `' '` space, an empty string will yield true:

```
DECLARE @EmptyString NVARCHAR(12) = '';

SELECT IIF(RIGHT(@EmptyString, 1) = ' ', 1, 0); -- this returns 1
```

The above is because of the Microsoft's [implementation of string comparisons](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces).

So, how fast exactly?

You can try the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource 
(
    [RowID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[value] NVARCHAR(1024)
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([value])
SELECT TOP (1000000) 'text ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number) AS VARCHAR(12)) 
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2

UPDATE #DataSource
SET [value] = [value] + ' '
WHERE [RowID] = 100000;


SELECT *
FROM #DataSource
WHERE ASCII(RIGHT([value], 1)) = 32;

SELECT *
FROM #DataSource
WHERE [value] LIKE '% ';
```

On my machine there is around 1 second difference:

[image]

I have test it on table with 600k rows, but larger size, and the difference was above 8 seconds. So, how fast exactly will depend on your real case data.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this by using [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like below:

```
select col1 from table1
WHERE charindex(' ', reverse(col1)) = 1
```

See example [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04faeb/1)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use below query to get values having any number of spaces in begining or at end of values in column.

```
 select * from table_name where column_name like ' %' or column_name like '% ';
```

Answer (score -1):

We can try underscore to find the entries which are blanks,though not an accurate solution like using '% %' or ' ', But I could find entries which are blanks.

select col_name from table where col_name like '_'

Comment: That will find all values which start with ANY character.