# How to identify rows that are having white spaces after a full patient name in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, database, whitespace, hana

Please provide the code to identify white spaces after a full patient name in SAP HANA

E.g:
`Abb qwerty wert`

As u can see the above scenario there is white space after patient name. The white space can vary from single to many white space character.  How to identify rows that has white spaces?

Require an SQL query

E.g: `SELECT * FROM NEW_REGISTRATION WHERE PATIENT_NAME LIKE ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2008: How to find trailing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552407/sql-server-2008-how-to-find-trailing-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM NEW_REGISTRATION WHERE PATIENT_NAME LIKE '% '
```

Comment: What if the white character space have more than 1 ,5 or 10 characters

Comment: As long as the whitespace is at the end it doesn't matter - the last character will always be a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [RTRIM](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-sql-reference-guide/rtrim-function-string), which can also be used to sanitize those entries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM NEW_REGISTRATION 
WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(PATIENT_NAME)) <> LENGTH(PATIENT_NAME)
```

Consequently there is also [LTRIM](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-sql-reference-guide/ltrim-function-string) and [TRIM](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-sql-reference-guide/trim-function-string).